# redactor-railsのconfig.jsが反映されない

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, redactor, heroku

config.jsでredactorエディタのmin-heightを調整したい（テキストエリアにある程度の高さを確保したい）のですが、ローカル環境で動作するもののherokuにデプロイすると設定が反映されなくなります。

ローカル環境とherokuの環境で挙動が異なる原因について心当たりありましたらご教示いただけないでしょうか。

- config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
  config.register_stylesheet 'redactor-rails.css'
  config.register_javascript 'redactor-rails.js'
```

- app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee

```
  #= require redactor-rails
```

Comment: redactorとherokuのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 1):

本家 SO に[解答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367657/rails-heroku-assets-not-being-included)と思われるものがありました（元ネタは GitHub の[このイシュー](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails/issues/16)です）。 
要約すると、

自分で `config.js` を作り、`app` の `asset` などに入れて、`#= require redactor-rails` と書く代わりに

```
#= require redactor-rails/redactor.min
#= require path/to/custom/config  （config.js へのパス）
```

と書くといいそうです。

原因は、`rake assets:precompile` タスクが gem 内の `config.js`（デフォルトのもの）を拾ってしまうからだそうです。

GitHub のイシューもしばらく更新がないので解決されていないものと思われます…